# How to override System.FeatureManagement.checkPackageBooleanValue in development org

Tags: apex, feature-management

We are trying to use - Feature Parameters in one of the applications we are building. Got most of the info from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/fma_manage_features.htm

Everything works fine, but how do I override the System.FeatureManagement.checkPackageBooleanValue in my developer org.

Because of the default value for the FeatureParameter most of Test cases are failing :( Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [demo project](https://github.com/forcedotcom/project-force), they include instructions for how to set the values both for testing in real mode and in unit test mode. I suspect that the answer you're really looking for is to set the preferred flag in your unit test:

```
// enable the param so we can continue our testing
FeatureManagement.setPackageBooleanValue('ExpenseTrackingPermitted',true);
```

This method only works in unit tests in your namespace. There's also ways to test this in your org by deploying metadata by updating a file in the `featureParameters` folder in your project files. I suggest you check out the project for more information.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I've to use System.runAs(user) { } after setting the FeatureParameter. In the developer org if I want to enable the same for manual testing, how do I do it?? apart from changing them in the package.

Comment: @SuryaChandraRaoGandreddi You need to expose a method to use it, such as a Visualforce page or Apex class. See `project-force/pf-app/main/default/classes/FeatureConsoleAPI.cls` as in example in the demo repository from the answer.